# How to avoid EOF Error when piping multiple files into a python script

Tags: shell, python-3.x, pipe, eof, xargs

I have a script that takes one or more files on as command line arguments and generates a bunch of plots. I would like to be able to use this script such that I can find all relevant files and pipe them to the script. Thus I have the following call:

```
find $PWD/somedir/ -path '*_d0/final/*' -name 'somefile.gz' -print0|sort -z |xargs -0 python smth.py
```

So far so good... The issue though is that I need some input from the user, regarding which columns to use (want the script to be flexible) and later on what to name the output figures.

That's where it breaks, I get a `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` at the first `input()` call. I understand that using pipes tie the stdin and stdout of different programs to each other and thus calling `input()` to read from stdin later in the script doesn't work.

How do I navigate around this? I thought of alternative ways to get input from the user, like with a config file submitted at runtime but I don't like that solution as it's a bit of a drag to prepare config files for each run. There should be a simpler way to solve this issue.

Suggestions?

Comment: How about temporarily storing the output of pipe to a file and then run your python script as a second command, asking user input and reading selective values from stored output?

Comment: @FurhanS. not sure what you mean, can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2):

In my system, man xargs proposes the `-o` option specifically for that:

> -o      Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing
>                the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an interactive application.

That means that you should simply use:

```
find $PWD/somedir/ -path '*_d0/final/*' -name 'somefile.gz' -print0|sort -z |xargs -0 -o python smth.py
```

Comment: Which version of xargs do you have?

Comment: I have this option on my mac but not on the remote server I ssh to.. That's a bit odd since the version on the Ubuntu server is from 2016 (GNU findutils 4.7.0)

Comment: Interesting. The xargs on my Linux server — which does have a working `-o` flag — reports `--version` as  `xargs (GNU findutils) 4.7.0` with a 2019 copyright.

Answer (score 1):

For reference [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/427881/62309) gives some insight as to why the problem occurs. Shortly put, `xargs` by default points the stdin to `/dev/null`, since it doesn't know what it should otherwise be. While there is a nice way to go around this issue on BSD xargs (by providing `-o` flag), the fellows at GNU findutils [seem to think](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?21734) that `echo foo bar | xargs sh -c 'emacs "$@" < /dev/tty' emacs` is a nicer way to do it.

In this case it ends up looking something like this:

```
find $PWD/somedir/ -path '*_d0/final/*' -name 'somefile.gz' -print0|sort -z |xargs -0 bash -c '</dev/tty python myscript.py "$@"' ignoreme
```

It works but I'd have to respectfully disagree with the devs at GNU findutils, it's a terribly clumsy way to circumvent the issue for the end user. I am still hoping to find a better solution for this problem.

Nevertheless I'll provide this answer as a reference for others who might run into similar problems, just in case this actually turns out to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it step-wise? Something like below:

Step 1 - find the data and store it in a temp file

```
 find $PWD/somedir/ -path '*_d0/final/*' -name 'somefile.gz' -print0|sort -z >> output.out
```

Step 2 - Use your python script to do whatever you desire with it, based on user input

```
python smth.py < output.out
```

In your python script, save the data from output.out into a temp var, to be acted upon based on user input.

Comment: So you are suggesting to create a file that has a list of files in it, which is then used as input to python script? What does the `<<` do? will it not block the stdin for the python script?

Comment: @posdef yes. Write the contents to a file, if thats an option. Replaced << with < to read the whole file contents at script startup. You can use other file reading mechanics in python for that purpose. Is it doable in your scenario?